# xdotool ignores target window

Tags: linux, automation, x11

A window named Teeworlds is my target window to send mouse clicks.

```
 xdotool search --class Teeworlds click --repeat 30000 --delay 20 1
```

However, these mouse clicks aren't sent just to the window, they are sent wherever the mouse is targeted, be it urxvt, or Firefox, or AwesomeWM's wibox.

As a result, the Teeworlds window doesn't receive any clicks until I focus the mouse on it.

I have tried using `xdotool selectwindow` to capture the window ID and then use:

```
xdotool click --window /16777230/ --repeat 30000 --delay 20 1
```

but the result is the same.